# How to do REST Template third API call?

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest

I am using the following code:

```
public static String getResponse(String jsonString) throws Exception {

    final String uri = "some_url_which_accepts_string";

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class, jsonString);

    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
}
```

but I am not able to call it properly. Is the syntax wrong or I am missing something?

Comment: What is the Exception you are getting

Comment: cannot find local variable jsonString error but this jsonString is holding the desired string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are expected ways.

```
getForObject(URI url, Class<T> responseType) 

 getForObject(String url, Class<T> responseType, Object... uriVariables)

 getForObject(String url, Class<T> responseType, Map<String,?> uriVariables)
```

And How are you passing the String
or else can you create one hashMap and try as below?

1. if you passing any query params then try as below

   ```
    String URL = some_url_which_accepts_string?param={param}

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
       map.put("param", "paramvalue");

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class, map);
   ```
2. Or you can try as below

```
URI targetUrl= UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(some_url_which_accepts_string) 
    .path("path")                            
    .queryParam("name", value)                                
    .build()                                                 
    .encode()                                                
    .toUri();                                                

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            String result = restTemplate.getForObject(targetUrl, String.class);
```